# Using tapply in Shiny to find mean of a column

Tags: r, shiny, tapply

I am running into trouble using the tapply function.  I am pulling two vectors from the same data frame which was created from a reactive variable.  The first I am calling from a user inputted selection, and the second is one that I have created to keep my code generalisable and to use in my sort function.  My sample code is shown below using the r-bloggers example.  The data is here.
https://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_150821851345614&key=949efb41171ac6ec1bf7f206d57e90b8&libId=j8v6cnh201021u9s000DAhzunvtas&loc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.r-bloggers.com%2Fbuilding-shiny-apps-an-interactive-tutorial%2F&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fdeanattali.com%2Ffiles%2Fbcl-data.csv&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fduckduckgo.com%2F&title=Building%20Shiny%20apps%20%E2%80%93%20an%20interactive%20tutorial%20%7C%20R-bloggers&txt=here

The error it throws is that they are not the same length, even though their attribute and class print outs are exactly the same.
I know that this is not the best code in the world, but I just threw together a quick example.

```
    library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
bcl <- read.csv("bcl-data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Sampling Strategies"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput("XDATA","xdata",
                                choices = c(names(bcl))),
                    selectInput("YDATA","ydata",
                                choices = c(names(bcl)))
                  ),

                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("The table",tableOutput("mytable"))
                    ))
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filtered <- reactive({
    bcl <- bcl %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(bcl))
  })

  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    dataset <- filtered() %>% mutate(sampled = "white")
    sample.rows <- sample(dataset$ID, 5, replace = FALSE)
    dataset$sampled[sample.rows] <- "black"
    final <- tapply(dataset[input$XDATA], list(dataset$sampled),mean)[["black"]]

    return(final)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Cheers
Edit* Sorry my bad, forgot to change over the drop list codes.  All I am interested is one generic xdata vector that can be selected from the loaded data set.  I then sample it, and want to find the mean value from the sampled indices.

Comment: I think instead of `data.frame(dataset$sampled)` it should be `list(dataset$sampled)`  Also, your first argument seems to be data.frame.  Please clarfiy what you wanted with a reproducible example

Comment: What are those xdata, ydata?

Comment: Edited.  All I want it to do is to return to me the mean value of the sampled indices from column that is designated input$XDATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is in the subsetting.  the `[` still returns a `data.frame`.  So, we need `[[`.  If we look at `?tapply`

> tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., default = NA, simplify = TRUE)

where

> X is an atomic object, typically a vector

---

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Sampling Strategies"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput("XDATA","xdata",
                                choices = c(names(bcl)[5:7])),
                    selectInput("YDATA","ydata",
                                choices = c(names(bcl)))
                  ),

                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("The table",tableOutput("mytable"))
                    ))
                ))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filtered <- reactive({
    bcl <- bcl %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
  })



  output$mytable <- renderTable({

    dataset <- filtered() %>% mutate(sampled = "white")
    sample.rows <- sample(dataset$ID, 20, replace = FALSE)
    dataset$sampled[sample.rows] <- "black"
    final <- tapply(dataset[[input$XDATA]], list(dataset$sampled),mean, na.rm = TRUE, simplify = TRUE)

    return(final)


  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had tried the double brackets but with dataset$sampled as a data frame.  Was running checks and they were coming up exactly the same in terms of attributes.  Cheers for the help!  Upvoted, but I'm a newbie to SO so it doesn't really count.  Sorry bout that.